# VBA - Append cell values to an empty array

Tags: excel, vba, append, dynamic-arrays

I would like to know how to append a value in an empty dynamic array.

I have defined the following array which is empty

```
Dim ratioArray As Variant
```

And then, based on a specific IF-condition I would like to append values if the condition is true. So what I tried as follow but it returns run-time error '13'.

```
ReDim Preserve ratioArray(UBound(ratioArray) + 1)
ratioArray = Cells(8+a,4+o)
```

a and o are integer variables.

What's wrong with the ReDim Preserve?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: the error may not be with the redim statement but the next line `ratioArray = Cells(8+a,4+o)` you are not telling vba into which slot to put the value: `ratioArray(Ubound(ratioArray)) = Cells(8+a,4+o)`

Comment: Actually, when I run the code, it gives the error in the ReDim statement. I just run your suggestion and also gives run time error '13'.

Comment: First of all, you need a `Dim ratioArray() As Variant` instead of `Dim ratioArray As Variant`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just an example as a working solution:

```
Sub Test()

    Dim ratioArray() As Variant

    ReDim ratioArray(1)
    ReDim Preserve ratioArray(UBound(ratioArray) + 1)
    ratioArray(1) = Cells(1, 1)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks tretom. It's working. I needed to define a dimension of the array and redimension it to include the first element. It solved my question!

Comment: I want to append array b() at the end of array a() which is going to devolve the sequence of values into array c(). How could I do? I tried by two different ways: i) creating a function; ii) c() = a() and then I have to append the array b() which is where I can't get this done. Some help please!

Comment: If I get it right, you have to save the length of array a() into a variable (say lenOrigA) Redim Preserve your array a() with the lenght of array a() + length of array b() and then fill the values from array b() into array a() from the position of lenOrigA

Comment: Actually you need to ReDim array c() to c(1 To UBound(a) + UBound(b)) to give you the length of array c(). Then, for each position i To UBound(a), c(i) = a(i,1) and move for next i. Then to append the second array b(), your first position will be UBoun(a) + 1 To UBound(a) + Ubound(b) and your third array c(i) = b(i - UBound(a), 1) and move for the next position

Answer (score 0):

`UBound(ratioArray)` fails because the variant is not known to be an array at that time.

Make it an array: `Dim ratioArray() As Variant`

However it will still fail because the array is dimensionless, you need to call `Redim ratioArray(0)` at some point prior to reading its `Ubound()`.

When assigning a single value, use an index:

```
ratioArray(0) = Cells(8+a,4+o)
```

Comment: Thanks Alex K. The problem was the array was dimensionless.